# Why LanguageTool is not working on LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, language

I am using LibreOffice `7.2.2.2`. I have installed LanguageTool `5.4`, then `5.5.1`, but none of them are working. They only add buttons to the toolbar, though they do not react. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my distribution from fedora 35 to debian 11, because fedora 35 failing everywhere. So I got a more intuitive error: `

```
(com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException){{Message="[JavaVirtualMachine]:An unexpected error occurred while searching for Java, 11 ./stoc/source/javavm/javavm.cxx:634", Context = (com.sun.star.uno.XInterface)@0}}
```

Finally, I solved it with this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/458240/unable-to-install-languagetool-2-5-extension-for-libreoffice-4-2-on-ubuntu-14-04